# Which architecture to use to retrieve database updates

Tags: android, node.js, cassandra

I am working on a project with front-end, back-end and mobile application.

The stack is the following :

- Mobile application : Android
- Backend:  Node.js
- Front-end: Angular 8
- Database: Cassandra

When the user connect to the mobile application, he retrieves the data of the database and they displayed to him on the mobile.
But these datas can be updated by another source like front-end.

And the problem is how to notify the mobile application about this ? What is the best architecture for this ?

Using WebSocket or Mqtt and listen all the modification of the database in backend ?
Requesting the backend from the mobile all x times ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question but here is can't be the best ultimate solution for every cases.

Heartbeat(request every x sec) is one of the option but it depends on your app. Here is a few more variants.

Take a look on firestore live data.  https://medium.com/@deepak140596/firebase-firestore-using-view-models-and-livedata-f9a012233917 when frontend will be updated and notify backend about it backend could notify firestore and your app will observe this event.

Or another way is silent push https://sheroes.tech/silent-push-notification-process-for-an-android-application-a4d7d2c568fc you can send push to notify app that it have to update some data.

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Troyanskii the solution with firestore is exactly what I need